# Some numbers are arranged together. Horizontally, they are equal difference series. Vertically, they are equal difference series. What series is this？

Tags: combinatorics

$$
\begin{matrix}
4 & 6 & 8 & 10 & 12 & 14 & 16 \\
6 & 9 &12 & 15 & 18 & 21 & 24 \\
8 & 12 & 16 & 20 & 24 & 28 & 32 \\
10 & 15 & 20 & 25 & 30 & 35 & 40 \\
12 & 18 & 24 & 30 & 36 & 42 & 48 \\
14 & 21 & 28 & 35 & 42 & 49 & 56 \\
16 & 24 & 32 & 40 & 48 & 56 & 64 \\
18 & 27 & 36 & 45 & 54 & 63 & 72 \\
20 & 30 & 40 & 50 & 60 & 70 & 80 \\
\end{matrix}
$$

These numbers are equal difference series horizontally and equal difference series vertically. What sequence is this?

You can continue to extend the arithmetic sequence to the right or downward. All the composite numbers are on these arithmetic sequences. All prime numbers are not on these arithmetic sequences.

The characteristics of its distribution are as follows: the statistical range is doubled, and the expanded part and the unexpanded part are composed of some identical arithmetic sequences. Using the principle of inclusion and exclusion, it can be calculated that the quantities of different elements in these two parts are similar.

Similarly:

Twin primes can also form such an arithmetic sequence. The numbers on the arithmetic sequence are all non twin primes, while the numbers not on the arithmetic sequence are all twin primes. Its distribution characteristics are exactly the same as prime numbers. It can also be considered that the number of twin primes in the two intervals before and after the expansion of the statistical range is approximately the same.

No one may believe this view, as long as the statistics to a large number, we will see this distribution characteristics. For example, expand the statistical scope to $10000000000$.

Comment: Your question would be much easier to decipher if you formatted it with
[MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  Specifically, search 
for the keyword : Arrays, in [this article](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Please edit your question, formatting the data into a table.

Comment: Resembles a 2 dimensional multiplication table, with rows at the top and columns on the left removed.

Answer (score 0):

On non twin primes

After adding 1 and 3 to each natural number in the natural number set n within 10, a pair of new numbers with 1 and 3 bits can be formed. If the pair of numbers are twin primes, the corresponding elements in the n set are put into the a set, otherwise they are put into the B set. If two new numbers 41 and 43 are formed by adding the numbers 1 and 3 after the number "4" in the n set, which are a pair of twin primes, "4" will be put into the a set. In this way, four numbers 1, 4, 7 and 10 should be put into set a according to this rule, while the remaining numbers 2, 3, 5, 6, 8 and 9 should be put into set B according to this rule. Obviously, a and B are complementary sets, and can refer to four pairs of twin primes (11-13, 41-43, 71-73, 101-103) and six pairs of non twin primes (21-23, 31-33, 51-53, 61-63, 81-83, 91-93) with 1 and 3 in natural number 109, respectively. In fact, after any element in B set is filled with bits 1 and 3, at least one of the two new numbers formed is a composite number.

Twin primes have complements or sets similar to complements. This set can indirectly refer to non twin primes, which makes it possible to screen out twin primes.

So how to find the elements in B set, that is, the non twin primes?

Group 1:

3、6、9、12、15......

14、27、40、53、66......

25、48、71、94、117......

36、69、102、135、168......

47、90、133、176、219......

...............................................

Group 2

6、13、20、27、34......

15、32、49、66、83......

24、51、78、105、132......

33、70、107 、144、181......

42、89、136 、183、230......

...............................................

Group 3

12、23、34、45、56......

23、44、65、86、107......

34、65、96、127、158......

45、86、127 、168、209......

56、107 、158、209、260......

...............................................

Group 4:

2、 5、 8、 11、14......

9、 22、35、48、61......

16、39、62、85、108......

23、56、89、122、155......

30、73、116、159、202......

...............................................

Group 5:

8、17、26、35、44......

17、36、55、74、93......

26、55、84、113、142......

35、74、113、152、191......

44、93、142、191、240......

...............................................

Any one of the five groups of bidirectional arithmetic sequence is followed by bits 1 and 3 to form two new numbers, which must not be a group of twin primes. However, the integer numbers that are not on the five two-way arithmetic sequence will form two new numbers by adding bits 1 and 3 after them, which must be twin prime numbers.

For example, the first number 3 in the first group is added with bits 1 and 3 respectively to form two numbers 31 and 33. Obviously, this is not a group of twin primes. The integer number 4, which is not on the five groups of two-way arithmetic sequence, is filled with bits 1 and 3 respectively to form 41 and 43, which are a group of twin prime numbers.

Here we only study the twin primes and non twin primes with 1 and 3.